# How do you add an attachment to x-mailer?

Tags: php

How do I add an attachment to this PHP with x-mailer?

```
$headers = "From: ($full_name)".
' '.$email_from."\r\n" .
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
"Reply-To: ($reply_to)" . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
header("Location: $thankyou");
?>
<script>location.replace('<?php echo $thankyou;?>')</script>
<?php
}
die();
?>
```

i filled this in why does it not work?

```
<?php
require 'class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mandrillapp.com';                 // Specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // Set the SMTP port
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'MANDRILL_USERNAME';                // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'MANDRILL_APIKEY';                  // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Your From name';
$mail->AddAddress('josh@example.net', 'Josh Adams');  // Add a recipient
$mail->AddAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional

$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <strong>in bold!</strong>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}
```

it says "HTTP 500 error
That’s odd… the website can’t display this page
The site may be undergoing maintenance or could have a programming error."
    echo 'Message has been sent';

Comment: Don’t try to do this yourself using `mail`, this is rather complex and easy to get wrong. Use a library like PHPMailer or Swift Mailer instead.

Comment: @misorude could you put a working example of phpmailer with my variables?

Comment: No, try it yourself first. You can ask here when you have specific questions or problems with it. But asking for an “example” in a situation like this would basically mean doing the work for you.

Comment: @misorude I have looked up about phpmailer and it says you need an smtp server but I don't have one

Comment: You don’t need your own server, you just need credentials to an e-mail account that you can use to send the mails with - that could for example be a Google Mail account, or whatever else you have. This basically just needs the same SMTP data that you need to send mails from within your mail client.

Comment: @misorude oh, ok, `$mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
$mail->SetFrom($email_from, $name_from);` how would I fill this in?

Comment: @misorude I have edited my question please look

Comment: A 500 Internal Server Error _always_ means that you check the error log first of all.

Comment: @misorude it says _The media query -ms-viewport has been deprecated_ and _CONSOLE21301: serviceWorker.getRegistrations is rejected due to unsecure context or host restriction in ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge/assets/errorpages/http_500.htm_

Comment: That sound like client-side error messages from the browser console? You have an error with your _server-side_ scripting, so you need to go check the logs on the server ...

Comment: @misorude how do I do that?

Comment: Depends, on your server configuration and/or hosting provider …

Comment: @misorude I have 000webhost

Comment: Well then go read their documentation or search their FAQ and find out how to access the error logs (or if they are accessible to you at all in the first place.) We can not hold your hand every single step of the way here, you need to make a little more of an effort yourself.

Comment: @misorude will phpmyadmin have it?

Comment: No, phpMyAdmin is a frontend to admin your database. That has nothing whatsoever to do with errors caused by your own PHP code.

Comment: If your hoster doesn’t give you access to the error logs, then you should set up a local webserver for development purposes and try your code there first, where you have full control.

Comment: @misorude it says _require(class.phpmailer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory_

Comment: And …? If you can’t figure out what this error means by yourself, then go research it.

Comment: @misorude sorted it out, but it says now _Invalid address: Message has been sent_ but I have checked that is is a valid address

Answer (score 0):

You have to create $email_message like the following:

```
$headers = "From: ($full_name)".' '.$email_from."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="emailsectionseparator"; type="text/html"\r\n";
"Reply-To: ($reply_to)" . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$email_message = "--emailsectionseparator\r\n";
$email_message.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset="ISO-8859-1"\r\n";
and so on ...

$email_message.= "--emailsectionseparator--\r\n";

mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
header("Location: $thankyou");
?>
<script>location.replace('<?php echo $thankyou;?>')</script>
<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Follow this sheme:

```
--emailsectionseparator
Content-Type: text/html; charset="US-ASCII"

Here goes the HTML content:


--emailsectionseparator
Filename: <filename>
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Base64

ABX1JKADFjkad91/291... 50k of base64 data here...

--emailsectionseparator--
```

and set the Content-Header to the following:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="emailsectionseparator"; type="text/html"
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand, could you add my php into it

Comment: I did. But I think you should follow the advice of misorude. Use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer, so you don't have to worry about your message body

Comment: how come it doesn't work if I just add to it `AddAttachment:`

Comment: You try to create a really raw email. So you have to write everything on your own. Something like addAttachment is the luxury of PHPMailer.